# Visual Studio Code - WordWrap only specific file formats

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make Visual Studio Code Word-Wrap only specific files (`.py`, `.cpp`, etc) and not utilities formats such as `.txt`, `.json`, etc?

I just started working on a project and I need to process a lot of txt files and it's annoying not seeing how the content of the file is structured because of the Wordwrap setting.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by customizing your `settings.json`. The quickest way is to use the command palette `(CTRL or CMD)+P` and begin typing `configure language`

[image: command palette]

followed by the file type you are specifically looking to alter

[image]

you can then customize the settings as needed. The code below can be added to your `settings.json` file to make `JSON` and `.txt` files always use word wrapping by default

```json
{
    ...
    "[plaintext]": {
      "editor.wordWrap": "on"
    },
    "[json]": {
      "editor.wordWrap": "on"
    }
}
```

more information can be found in the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings)

Comment: Any idea how to do this for `.sh` files? I'm not sure what it corresponds to in the popup menu. I wish we could do this by file type instead of another name, the mapping between which we have to figure out ourselves..

Comment: @aviator yes, you need to use `[shellscript]` as the key. If you open the command pallette (ctrl/cmd+p) and try to change the language using the `change language mode` command, you can see a list of names and short codes

Comment: also, when editing the `settings.json` file, you should see some relevant autocomplete appear after adding a new line and typing the open bracket for the language setting, `"[`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that solves my issue. I guess my underlying complaint is that we are supposed to just know that the `shellscript` language in the autocomplete menu is apparently responsible for the file type `.sh`, which was frankly not immediately evident to me (and maybe other less experienced programmers as well). It would seem much more intuitive to me if word wrap (and whatever other settings) was configurable simply based on mere file extensions, but not to the VS Code developers I guess..

Comment: This is excellent, I had no idea that language-specific settings could be modified in the UI. Looks like you can also open settings normally and then then, in the search bar, type `@lang:json` (or whatever language) followed by a space. You'll now see `[JSON]` next to each settings tab. You can enter a search term after the space if desired.

Comment: Note that if you want to set it to the `editor.wordWrapColumn` value, `editor.wordWrap` needs to be set to `"bounded"` instead of `"on"`.